# Unlock nodes on grab/mousedown event, can not move them immediately in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

At first **all my nodes are locked**. I would like to unlock all of them on drag event. I tried the following solution with no success:

```
cy.nodes().on('grab', function() {
    cy.nodes().unlock();    
});
```

I realized that **'grab' event does not occur on locked nodes**, so **I changed it to 'mousedown' instead**. Now if I click on a node and hold it, every node unlocks as expected, but **I can not move immediately the node I clicked, I have to release the button then drag the node again.**
Is there a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not depend on undocumented behaviour for when locked checks happen.  Consider that when the checks happen might change from version to version.  Consider touch device support.

Instead, you should lock nodes only when they need to be locked.  If you want nodes to be grabbable, then they should not be locked by default.  You should use locking only when necessary, perhaps during layout, and unlock immediately afterwards.

Comment: I am working on a project, where you can save nodes' position to a database, and to prevent users to overwrite each other's modification I am using locks. First all of my nodes are locked. You can send a modification request where I check the database using ajax, and if no one has lock on the topology, I unlock the nodes.